# Sending Api Request with string category to Mysql Database server through Retrofit2 but not working

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, retrofit2

I am sending Api request through Retrofit2 to Mysql Database to fetch data but am sending one category in string with Api request to check if my data is available according to that category.It is going in if condition in php script and giving me catid is null please check my code. I am giving catid why is it passing if condition and giving catid is null?

Note: If I give catid hard code to php script it gives me result according to that category. I think problem in posting catid with Api request.Guide me please

```
@GET("fetchtext.php")
Call<ArrayList<DataStored>> savePost(@Query("catId") String catId);
```

Here I am sending request to server:

```
 mAPIService.savePost(category).enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<DataStored>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<DataStored>> call, Response<ArrayList<DataStored>> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: 2"+response.body());
                arrayList=  response.body();
              myRecyclerAdapter.addItems(arrayList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<DataStored>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: 2"+t.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

My Php script:

```
    <?php 
    $db_name="discount";
    $mysql_username="root";
    $mysql_password="nwpas";
    $server_name="localhost";
    $con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);
    $catid=$_POST["catId"];
    if(empty($catid)){
echo "catid is null";
    }
    else{
    $sql = "SELECT branchName,brands.brandsName 
      FROM branch Inner Join brands on branch.brandsID=brands.brandsID WHERE brands.catID=$catid" ;
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $result = array();
    if (!$r) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        exit();
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        array_push($result,array(
            'brancname'=>$row['branchName'],
            'brandsNae'=>$row['brandsName']

        ));
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: can you post the json response?

Comment: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ <br>.....Here it is

Comment: No, I mean the json response and this error is saying, you are asking for ArrayList<DataStored> but the json returned a String

Comment: First of all, you need to send a json response not the direct php file, and then only retrofit will work.

Comment: how to send Json Response ?

Comment: I used post php instead of get so that's why error was coming no its fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making a `GET` request using retrofit change your php code to accept `GET` params. Currently your code is configured to send a `GET` request from `android` but in the `php` end you are accepting a `POST` request

In your php code, change

```
$catid=$_POST["catId"];
```

to

```
$catid=$_GET["catId"];
```

Alternatively if you prefer not to change the php side, then make a post request with retrofit using `@POST` and then passing the `catId` in body